# transform the square wave of a voltage inverter into a sine wave

Tags: inverter, 555, sine

I'm building a voltage inverter to power a refrigerator compressor, to lower the cost and simplify the project. I chose to use mosfet irfz44n on the primary part of the inverter, which however will produce a square wave on the output.
however, in tests, the design did not start the motor because the square wave of the circuit prevents starting, which is done via a starting capacitor.
I thought about putting an rc filter but as the motor reaches 400w at startup I didn't find a nice topology because of the current and the resistor.
would be able to turn this circuit the way it is without much modification into a sinusoidal output?
(picture below)
[image]

Comment: Look up sine-triangle PWM.

Comment: What about an LC filter?

Comment: You are creating short across supply with the common emitter when you should be using common base with a dead band of xx ns or a better method of driving one polarity only during transition

Comment: this doesn't seem to have *any* feedback from the output side, so it is unlikely to resonate by itself, and the 555 is an adequate choice to give you a higher-frequency PWM so you could drive this in a synthesized-sine wave fashion. In other words: not a acceptable inverter!